# How to accept popup message from Edge in IE mode Python - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

When I try to download a file from Edge in IE mode, I get a confirmation message for this download and I don't know how to overcome it, it doesn't allow me to accept commands like ALT + G, it doesn't matter if the file is, since what would matter is overcome this step of accepting (Save) or, failing that, some configuration that allows downloading without this message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzyWU.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=Service(executable_path="C:\IEDriverServer_Win32_4.14.0\IEDriverServer.exe"))
driver.get("https://www.winrar.es/descargas")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),"Descargue WinRAR ahora")]").click()
```

I already tried sending

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('g').key_up(Keys.ALT).perform()
```

but it doesn't work, just like sending it directly through js and neither

Comment: May I know if you have checked my answer? If there's any question, you can share with us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't interact with the download popup using only Selenium commands. Selenium can't handle this popup. You need to take a look at tools like AutoIT to handle this popup.

If you want to simply skip this popup, you can try Wget:

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
ie_options.attach_to_edge_chrome = True
ie_options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
ie_options.edge_executable_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"

driver = webdriver.Ie(options=ie_options)

# We directly go to second URL to avoid auto-download, and avoid the popup.
driver.get("https://www.winrar.es/descargas/101/descargar-winrar-para-windows-x64-en-ingles")
# Get download URL
download = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='subcontent']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a")
url_download = download.get_attribute("href")
# Download the file with Wget
os.system('cmd /c C:\\Windows\\System32\\wget.exe -P c:\\temp --no-check-certificate ' + url_download)
```